# Error: Invalid resource directory name Adding layout folder

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I get an error while adding a layout for xsmall devices.
I created a folder named layout-xsmall and whenever I try to run the code it says

```
src\main\res\layout-xsmall: Error: Invalid resource directory name
```

I'm trying to make an special layout for just xsmall devices 
should I use a different name for xsmall devices?

Comment: it should be `layout-small` whats `layout-xsmall` what size ?

Answer (score 0):

```
`res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size 
  ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in 
landscape orientation`orientation
```